# Match set of dictionaries. Most elegant solution. Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Given two lists of dictionaries, new one and old one. Dictionaries represent the same objects in both lists.
I need to find differences and produce new list of dictionaries where will be objects from new dictionaries only and updated attributes from old dictionaries.
Example:

```
   list_new=[
             { 'id':1,
               'name':'bob',
               'desc': 'cool guy'
              },
             
             { 'id':2,
               'name':'Bill',
               'desc': 'bad guy'
              },

              { 'id':3,
               'name':'Vasya',
               'desc': None
              },
        ]

    list_old=[
             { 'id':1,
               'name':'boby',
               'desc': 'cool guy',
                'some_data' : '12345'
              },
             { 'id':2,
               'name':'Bill',
               'desc': 'cool guy',
               'some_data' : '12345'

              },
              { 'id':3,
               'name':'vasya',
               'desc': 'the man',
               'some_data' : '12345'
              },
              { 'id':4,
               'name':'Elvis',
               'desc': 'singer',
               'some_data' : '12345'
              },
            ]
```

In that example I want produce new list where will be only new guys from list_new with updated data. Matched by `id`. So Bob will become Boby, Bill will become coll guy, Vasya become  - the man. End Elvis have to be absent.

Give me an elegant solution. With less amount of iteration loops.

There is way, I resolve that. Which is not the best:

```
 def match_dict(new_list, old_list)
    ids_new=[]
    for item in new_list:
            ids_new.append(item['id'])
    result=[] 
    for item_old in old_medias:
        if item_old['id'] in ids_new:
            for item_new in new_list:
                if item_new['id']=item_old['id']
                    item_new['some_data']=item_old['some_data']
                    result.append(item_new)
    return result
```

The reason why I'm doubt, because there is loop inside loop. If there will be lists of 2000 items the process would take same time.

Comment: Are you retrieving this list from somewhere? Can you restructure the list of dictionaries using the __id__ as a key to a dictionary?

Comment: I tried to use your code to diff your output with mine, but it doesn't work (syntax errors etc.). Please fix, thanks.

Comment: The dictionaries going from mongodb. I'm trying to make it editable through django admin interface. I have typical django formset and dont want it to push each dict separately, It would make a lot of hits to database per one save in a page with formset. So i want to get it, match it, and than push with one hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

- Create a look up dictionary for list_old by id
- Loop through list_new dicts creating a merged dict for each if it existed in old

Code:

```
def match_dict(new_list, old_list): 
    old = dict((v['id'], v) for v in old_list)
    return [dict(d, **old[d['id']]) for d in new_list if d['id'] in old]
```

EDIT: incorrectly named variables inside function.

Comment: I like that solution. Beautiful. But it already was given by  koblas. Thanks.

Comment: Only one problem is here that it dont save new objects. which can come as well. But I did not mentioned about it.

Comment: Just for reference this function doesn't return a result that matches the original match_dict() function.  Since it has the lists reversed.

Comment: @koblas are you referring to the typos? new_list/list_new old_list/list_old.  Those are a mistake.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

Can't quite get it to one line, but here's a simpler version:

```
def match_new(new_list, old_list) :
    ids = dict((item['id'], item) for item in new_list)
    return [ids[item['id']] for item in old_list if item['id'] in ids]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the constraints of your data, I will suppose that `id` is unique in each list, and that your list contains only imutable types (string, int,...) which are hashable.

```
# first index each list by id
new = {item['id']: item for item in list_new}
old = {item['id']: item for item in list_old}

# now you can see which ids appeared in the new list
created = set(new.keys())-set(old.keys())
# or which ids were deleted
deleted =  set(old.keys())-set(new.keys())
# or which ids exists in the 2 lists
intersect = set(new.keys()).intersection(set(old.keys()))

# using the same 'conversion to set' trick,
# you can see what is different for each item
diff = {id: dict(set(new[id].items())-set(old[id].items())) for id in intersect}

# using your example data set, diff now contains the differences for items which exists in the two lists:
# {1: {'name': 'bob'}, 2: {'desc': 'bad guy'}, 3: {'name': 'Vasya', 'desc': None}}

# you can now add the new ids to this diff
diff.update({id: new[id] for id in created})
# and get your data back into the original format:
list_diff = [dict(data, **{'id': id}) for id,data in diff.items()]
```

*this is using python 3 syntax, but should be easily ported to python 2.*

**edit:** here is the same code written for python 2.5:

```
new = dict((item['id'],item) for item in list_new)
old = dict((item['id'],item) for item in list_old)

created = set(new.keys())-set(old.keys())
deleted =  set(old.keys())-set(new.keys())
intersect = set(new.keys()).intersection(set(old.keys()))

diff = dict((id,dict(set(new[id].items())-set(old[id].items()))) for id in intersect)

diff.update(dict(id,new[id]) for id in created))
list_diff = [dict(data, **{'id': id}) for id,data in diff.items()]
```

*(note how the code is less readable without the dict comprehension)*

Comment: It's pretty good. There is 5 loops. But x*5 is less than x*x. if x sometime can equal 300. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

for each dictionary in old_list, search for the dictionary in new_list with the same id, then do:  `old_dict.update(new_dict)`

eliminate each new_dict, after updating, from new_list and append the remaining, unused dicts after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is what you need:

```
l = []
for d in list_old:
    for e in list_new:
        if e['id'] == d['id']:
            l.append(dict(e, **d))
print l
```

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-two-python-dictionaries-as-a-single-expression) on how to merge dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
def match_dict(new_list, old_list):
    new_dict = dict((obj['id'], obj) for obj in new_list)
    old_dict = dict((obj['id'], obj) for obj in old_list)
    for k in new_dict.iterkeys():
        if k in old_dict:
            new_dict[k].update(old_dict[k])
        else:
            del new_dict[k]
    return new_dict.values()
```

If you are doing this often I would suggest storing your data as dictionaries with the id as the key instead of lists, that way you wouldn't have to convert it each time.

**edit**: Here is an example showing how to store the data in a dictionary.

```
list_new = [{'desc': 'cool guy', 'id': 1, 'name': 'bob'}, {'desc': 'bad guy', 'id': 2, 'name': 'Bill'}, {'desc': None, 'id': 3, 'name': 'Vasya'}]
# create a dictionary with the value of 'id' as the key
dict_new = dict((obj['id'], obj) for obj in list_new)
# now you can access entries by their id instead of having to loop through the list
print dict_new[2]
# {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bill', 'desc': 'bad guy'}
```

Comment: What do you mean dictionaries as the key? Can I have some doc link? Or see some example?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be much better off if your top-level data structure was a dict rather than a list. Then it would be:

```
dict_new.update(dict_old)
```

However, for what you actually have, try this:

```
result_list = []
for item in list_new:
    found_item = [d for d in list_old if d["id"] == item["id"]]
    if found_item:
        result_list.append(dict(item, **found_item[0]))
```

This actually still has a loop inside a loop (the inner loop is "hidden" in the list comprehension) so it's still O(n**2). On large data sets it would undoubtedly be noticeably faster to convert it to a dict, update that, and then convert it back to a list.

Answer (score 0):

You could like this one:

```
def match_dict(new_list, old_list):
    id_new = [item_new.get("id") for item_new in list_new]
    id_old = [item_old.get("id") for item_old in list_old]

    for idx_old in id_old:
        if idx_old in id_new:
            list_new[id_new.index(idx_old)].update(list_old[id_old.index(idx_old)])

    return list_new

from pprint import pprint
pprint(match_dict(list_new, list_old))
```

Output:

```
[{'desc': 'cool guy', 'id': 1, 'name': 'boby', 'some_data': '12345'},
 {'desc': 'cool guy', 'id': 2, 'name': 'Bill', 'some_data': '12345'},
 {'desc': 'the man', 'id': 3, 'name': 'vasya', 'some_data': '12345'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[od for od in list_old if od['id'] in {nd['id'] for nd in list_new}]
```

Comment: This one does not update additional data which come with new dict.