# intersection of two lists of dictionaries by key/value pair

Tags: python, dictionary, intersection

I have two lists of dictionaries in the format:

```
systolic_sex = [
        {'attribute': u'bp', 'value_d': 133.0, 'value_s': u'133', 'sid': 6}, 
        {'attribute': u'bp', 'value_d': 127.0, 'value_s': u'127', 'sid': 17}, 
        {'attribute': u'bp', 'value_d': 121.0, 'value_s': u'121', 'sid': 18}, 
        {'attribute': u'bp', 'value_d': 127.0, 'value_s': u'127', 'sid': 27}, 
        {'attribute': u'bp', 'value_d': 120.0, 'value_s': u'120', 'sid': 42},
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 6},      
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 17},   
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 18},
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 27},   
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 42}
    ]



sex = [
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 6},      
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 17},   
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 42}
    ]
```

I want to match these lists by the value of the key 'sid,' so that if the same value of 'sid' is in both, I have a match, otherwise, I do not. If I have a match, I then append the matching dictionaries by 'sid' from both sets to a new list accordingly like so

```
new_set = [
        {'attribute': u'bp', 'value_d': 133.0, 'value_s': u'133', 'sid': 6}, 
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 6},
        {'attribute': u'bp', 'value_d': 127.0, 'value_s': u'127', 'sid': 17}, 
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 17},
        {'attribute': u'bp', 'value_d': 120.0, 'value_s': u'120', 'sid': 42},
        {'attribute': u'SEX', 'value_d': 0.0, 'value_s': u'M', 'sid': 42}
    ]
```

I've tried various methods of intersecting these, including modifying answers from [Match set of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5252519/match-set-of-dictionaries-most-elegant-solution-python), but I am looking to create a new list of dictionaries that have the matching sids, not replacing values between the two lists.

Comment: Can you show what the desired output should look like in this case?  Sounds like you effectively want to join the two "tables" on the `sid` "column"?

Comment: LOL the output was nothing like I imagined it for some reason. Deleted my answer.

Comment: It was a nice remapping of the data! Useful for future efforts.

Comment: NB: The set sex could be of the form systolic_sex, that is, having more than one set of different values for the 'attribute' key across a single value of the 'sid' key. For example, I could have two sets, systolic_sex and diastolic_sex, and then do the match of all keys by 'sid'. Sorry if this was not clear in the original post. In any case, @dawg's solution worked for this, even though I did not make this requirement clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be interested in using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) if you're dealing with data like this a lot. Your dictionaries are already in the form pandas likes, so you can do this:

```
import pandas

systolic_sex = pandas.DataFrame(systolic_sex)
sex = pandas.DataFrame(sex)

matches = systolic_sex[systolic_sex.sid.isin(sex.sid)]
```

If you want the data back in the same format as you supplied them, you can to

```
output = matches.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: I've actually used Pandas for manipulating data and would have had I not been able to use a python only approach. I actually like this solution much better than the one I accepted as an answer, since it is more parsimonious, minus the extra import.

Comment: Yeah, I find that Pandas is becoming quite standard wherever I go, so I don't think it's much overhead for the vastly better handling of data like these.

Comment: For what I had to do with it, it go a bit complicated. I will give it another chance.

Comment: Last step to convert DataFrame back to list of dictionaries is `matches.T.to_dict().values()` ... nice (you may have convinced me, especially since I have an upcoming project with a LOT of similar hoops to jump through)!

Comment: Oh, and I must comment that you are the rare breed of coder/data person I've seen actually use the correct subject-verb agreement for data! (**data are/datum is**)

Comment: Thanks. I'm a lecturer and pedantry goes with the territory. Note that if your data started life in json files (which it appears like) you can read directly into a dataframe with `pandas.read_json`, and the final step to convert is nicer as `matches.to_dict(orient='records')`

Comment: Pedantry is great! Probably confounds many people, especially if you correct them, like I always do! (^_^) Thanks for the tip. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the answer in the post you linked:

```
systolic_sex = dict((e['sid'], e) for e in systolic_sex)
sex = set(e['sid'] for e in sex)

matches = []
for sid,v in systolic_sex.items():
    if sid not in sex: continue
    matches.append(v)
```

Comment: I tried this based previous to edits, and it worked for the stated problem. However, I realized my first set should have been combined as systolic_sex. I have edited the original post accordingly.

Comment: Got it, partially, but I see where to go with it. Thanks for getting me back on track, and for teaching some new python tricks! (^_^)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> uniq=set(e['sid'] for e in sex) 
>>> filter(lambda d: d['sid'] in uniq, systolic_sex)
[{'attribute': u'bp', 'sid': 6L, 'value_s': u'133', 'value_d': 133.0},        
 {'attribute': u'bp', 'sid': 17L, 'value_s': u'127', 'value_d': 127.0},  
 {'attribute': u'bp', 'sid': 42L, 'value_s': u'120', 'value_d': 120.0}, 
 {'attribute': u'SEX', 'sid': 6L, 'value_s': u'M', 'value_d': 0.0}, 
 {'attribute': u'SEX', 'sid': 17L, 'value_s': u'M', 'value_d': 0.0}, 
 {'attribute': u'SEX', 'sid': 42L, 'value_s': u'M', 'value_d': 0.0}]
```

Comment: This is one of those cases where a list comprehension is both shorter and prettier: `[d for d in systolic_sex if d['sid'] in uniq]`

Comment: I just tested this on two more generalized data sets than I gave in my example (with arbitrary duplicates on the value of the key 'sid,' but with more than two non-duplicate values on the key 'attribute', and it worked as anticipated). The pandas solution would more than likely need a bit of tweaking, since it gave the same results @inspectorG4dget's solution gave, which required some tweaking for the more general case.

Comment: To get to the general case, pandas was he easiest of the suggestions to use.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following (as per @chtohnicdaemon):

```
import pandas
#-----> code snipped here
#----->
# iterate over record sets returned by SQLAlchemy to populate list
    for result in query_right:
        data = {'sid': result.patient_sid,
                'value_s': result.string_value,
                'value_d': result.double_value,
                'attribute': result.attribute_value}

                result_right.append(data)

    for result in left_child:
        data = {'sid': result.patient_sid,
                'value_s': result.string_value,
                'value_d': result.double_value,
                'attribute': result.attribute_value}

                result_left.append(data)

# convert list of dictionaries to data frames
right = pandas.DataFrame(right_result)
left = pandas.DataFrame(left_result)

# get matches
matches_right  = right[right.sid.isin(left.sid)]
matches_left  = left[left.sid.isin(right.sid)]

# combine matched sets into single set
frames = [matches_right,matches_left]

# concatenate data, drop duplicates and convert back to a list of dictionaries
result = pd.concat(frames).drop_duplicates().to_dict(orient='records')
```

Worked like a charm!

Comment: `drop_duplicates` doesn't work in-place, so that line isn't actually doing anything here. You also don't need the extra call to `pandas.Dataframe` in the "get matches" area. You can just do `pandas.concat(frames).drop_duplicates().to_dict(orient='records')` for all the parts from "concatenate sets" on down.

Comment: drop_duplicates worked from the python interpreter (I have yet to test it in my code). Other than that, I guess the extra data frames are indeed redundant, otherwise I like the single line. Mahalo!

Comment: You would have seen the result, but it is not stored. Few of the pandas functions work in place.

Comment: I see you're reading from a db. You can do it directly with [pandas.read_sql](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql.html)

Comment: Nice! Looks like I can do what I need to along the lines of reading `pandas.read_sql(query_right.statement, query_right.session.bind)` into a data frame... this will shave off a few clock ticks from processing time, especially when the returned record set is large, since I won't have to iterate through it to build the list.